# Multiple selection for wordpress widget

Tags: categories, customization, widgets, select

I created my own category selection widget. So i used `<select>` but i want to use with `multiple` attribute.

Here is my widget class. It works perfect without `multiple` attr. But i want to use it. And it must be return category ids in array.

```
<?php

class myCatWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function myCatWidget() {
        parent::WP_Widget( false, $name = 'My cat widget' );
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
        $postCats = $instance[ 'postCats' ];
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="widfat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postCats' ); ?>">Categories</label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postCats' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postCats' ); ?>" style="width: 100%;" multiple>
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                );

                $terms = get_terms( $args );
                foreach( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                    <option <?php selected( $instance[ 'postCats' ], $term->term_id ); ?> value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term->term_id ); ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <?php

    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
        $instance[ 'postCats' ] = esc_sql( $new_instance[ 'postCats' ] );
        return $instance;
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
        $postCats = $instance[ 'postCats' ];

        echo $before_widget;

        if( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }

        echo $postCats;

        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("myCatWidget");' ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi why don't you used multiple check-box instead of select option field. As well as you have used deprecated functions like "create_function". I have modified your code which replaced select option with multiple check-box selection.

```
function myCatWidget() {
    register_widget( 'my_custom_cat_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myCatWidget' );

class my_custom_cat_widget extends WP_Widget {

   function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct('my_custom_cat_widget', __('My cat widget', 'wpb_widget_domain'), 
            array( 'description' => __( 'Your description', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), ) 
        );
    }

public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = isset($instance[ 'title' ]) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : 'Categories';
    $instance['postCats'] = !empty($instance['postCats']) ? explode(",",$instance['postCats']) : array();
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="widfat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postCats' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select Categories you want to show:' ); ?></label><br />
        <?php $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
            );
            $terms = get_terms( $args );
        //print_r($terms);
         foreach( $terms as $id => $name ) { 
            $checked = "";
            if(in_array($name->name,$instance['postCats'])){
                $checked = "checked='checked'";
            }
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('postCats'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('postCats[]'); ?>" value="<?php echo $name->name; ?>"  <?php echo $checked; ?>/>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('postCats'); ?>"><?php echo $name->name; ?></label><br />
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <?php

}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
    $instance['postCats'] = !empty($new_instance['postCats']) ? implode(",",$new_instance['postCats']) : 0;
    return $instance;
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
    $postCats = $instance[ 'postCats' ];
    $categories_list = explode(",", $postCats);

    echo $before_widget;

    if( $title ) {
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    }

    $args = array('post_type' => 'post','taxonomy' => 'category',);
    $terms = get_terms( $args );
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($categories_list as $cat) {
                foreach($terms as $term) {
                    if($cat === $term->name) {
                        echo "<li>".$term->name."</li>";                                    
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}
}
```

Hope it will help to solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Put two brackets right after the select name like

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postCats' ); ?>"
```

will be named as

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postCats' ); ?>[]"
```

The complete array of options will then be returned as you expect.

Comment: So you're just adding [] to the end of the name attribute in HTML? I don't think that means anything special to HTML, no. Or are you hoping that the form will be submitted with many `field[]` attributes and PHP's form handler will parse that into an array somehow?